# How to Download a file in the browser programmatically in Puppeteer / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a requirement to automatically download files from the browser with Puppeteer, is this possible?

The way the app works, I click on a link and it prompts me to select the folder where I want to save the file, and specify the file name (optionally, if different from the default). Is there a way to hook into this and say "when I am prompted by the browser to select a folder and give a name, save it to **X** folder and give it **Y** name", programmatically?

Comment: it's possible, but maybe is much easier get the download link, and then request the file using any program without puppeteer?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.